# Load a stack of View Controllers from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

When I re-start the app I want to pop to the correct Question of an Assessment (the last one answered):

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard =[ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Assessment" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier : @"ImageQuestionViewController"];
UINavigationController *questionsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
ImageQuestionViewController *viewController =[questionsNavigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[viewController setQuestionNumber:0];
questionsNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
self.window.rootViewController = questionsNavigationController;
```

So I set the question number which creates the correct view, however, the previous button is meant to pop to the last instance of that view controller (Question number 1 - say):

```
- (IBAction)pressBack:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

However, when created from `AppDelegate` it doesn't obviously create the other view controllers underneath it, hence `popViewcontroller` doesn't work. I don't want to instantiate view controllers constantly so I don't want to change that code.

Is there a way to create a whole stack of view controllers essentially.

Thanks!

Comment: you can create one VC only and show previous and next question on same VC.. perform animation on push or pop

Comment: can't pop because there isn't a stack underneath

Comment: i am not talking about real popVC.. if user clicks back button just perform pop animation and reload the same VC